# Adding libraries to Makefile.am

Tags: compiling, dash, library, c, make

I am trying to add already existing library below to dash source code :
[Jerasure](https://github.com/tsuraan/Jerasure)

I have included all the source and header files in a directory 'jerasure' inside 'src'.

In the Makefile.am , I have added the below lines:

```
libbitcoin_server_a_SOURCES = \
  jerasure/cauchy.c \                                                          
  jerasure/galois.c \                                                          
  jerasure/liberation.c \                                                      
  jerasure/reed_sol.c \                                                        
  jerasure/timing.c \                                                          
  jerasure/encoder.c \                                                         
  jerasure/decoder.c \                                                         
  jerasure/jerasure.c \                                                        
 $(BITCOIN_CORE_H)
```

Headers are added as below:

```
BITCOIN_CORE_H = \
 jerasure/cauchy.h \                                                          
 jerasure/galois.h \                                                          
 jerasure/liberation.h \                                                      
 jerasure/reed_sol.h \                                                         
 jerasure/timing.h \                                                                                                                   
 jerasure/jerasure.h
```

I am getting the error :

> src/Makefile.am:324: warning: variable
>   'jerasure_libbitcoin_jerasure_a_SOURCES' is defined but no program or
>   src/Makefile.am:324: library has 'jerasure_libbitcoin_jerasure_a' as
>   canonical name (possible typo)

I have used Makefiles before, and I have been trying from sometime to get accustomed to Makefile.am idea, but not able to figure out how to get this to work.

I am able to compile this on my macOS, but not on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Please help me understand what should I do in order to get this library to be used.

If there is a way to compile this as a library, that would help too.
But right now

> I want to import the Source or Header files in to already existing CPP
>   files and be able to use the functionality.